# Incrementing a variable in a function does not increment it globally

Tags: python

I'm new to python and i'm having trouble with this:

```
def fun(x,y):
    if x>y:
        print "win", x+1
        x= x+1
        return x
a=1
b=10

if a==1:
    fun(b,a)

print b
```

The console prints: win 11
                    10

instead of the 10 at the end, i thought it waas going to be an 11. How do i fix this, and why does it happen?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To do what you want, you need to assign the return value to b:

b = fun(b, a)

Comment: -1 -- This is absolutely **wrong**. Python *never* passes any argument by value. *Anything* you handle is actually a *reference*. What python does is copying *the reference*. Plus numbers are immutable so in `a = 10; a += 1` a *new* `11` object is created and the reference `a` is *rebound* to the new object.

Answer (score 2):

I never programmed in Python
but I think this is the problem

```
if a==1:
    b=fun(b,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

```
 b=fun(b,a)
```

To have 11 as output

Comment: please include the complete code or at least explain his error and/or your solution